# Fortran only give outcome of the first term?

Tags: fortran

I was about to calculate the `cos(x)+1/4*cos(2x)`, however the result is always giving me outcome of only `cos(x)`. Where is the error in my code?

```
  program write
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: N=8
  integer :: j
  real :: h, L
  real, dimension(0:N-1) ::x, fx
  real(8), parameter :: pi=4.0_8*atan(1.0_8)
  L=2*pi

  h=L/N
  do j=0,N-1
     x(j)=h*j
  end do
  do j=0,N-1
     fx(j)=cos(x(j))+1/4*cos(2*x(j))
  end do

  write(*,*),fx


  end program write
```

Comment: `real(8)` is ugly and not portable. Instead, utilize names constants in `ISO_Fortran_env` or use `selected_real_kind` to control precision in a portable manner. The statement `1/4*cos(2*x(j))` is problematic. Please read http://www.fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html

Comment: 1/4 is integer division result 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the `1/4`.

Since both `1` and `4` are integer, `1/4` is interpreted as an integer division, and any reminder is dropped. In short: `1/4 == 0`, whereas `1.0/4 == 1/4.0 == real(1)/4 == 0.25`.

Note that `real(1/4) == real(0) == 0.0`.

Comment: Thank you so much!